# issue with resizing nautilus window in gnome metacity

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 15.04, metacity

Recently upgraded to ubuntu 15.04. Previously I was using gnome metacity as my desktop. (Couldn't work well with unity). I did not find any issues with the resizing in the last version I was using.

After the upgrade, and post noticing the issue on the gnome session, I loaded the unity desktop and verified the issue. It seems that I am able to successfully do the resize on that desktop.

Is this an issue with gnome metacity?